# Drush doesn't update on one of two servers

Tags: windows, drupal, drush

I have 2 different Windows 2016 Servers running Drupal 8 and Drush 9 is installed on both but I have a Drush verison mismatch that I'm trying to fix.

I have this global composer.json file on both servers:

```
{
    "require": {
        "drush/drush": "9.*"
    }
}
```

On my Test server, `drush --version` shows version 9.5.2.
On my Live server, `drush --version` shows version 9.7.0.

If I run `composer global update drush/drush` on my Test server, it doesn't update Drush and returns, "nothing to install or update".

I tried this:

```
composer global require drush/drush:9.7.0
```

and got this error:

```
Changed current directory to C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Composer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: consolidation/site-alias[3.0.0, 1.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: consolidation/site-alias[3.0.0, 1.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: consolidation/site-alias[3.0.0, 1.1.11].
    - drush/drush 9.7.0 requires consolidation/site-alias ^3.0.0@stable -> satisfiable by consolidation/site-alias[3.0.0].
    - Installation request for drush/drush 9.7.0 -> satisfiable by drush/drush[9.7.0].
    - Installation request for consolidation/site-alias (locked at 1.1.11) -> satisfiable by consolidation/site-alias[1.1.11].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comparing the line, `"name": "consolidation/site-alias",` in composer.lock in both environments, I see that Test has 1.1.11 and Live has 3.0.0.

I installed drupal/recommended-project and thought I followed the same steps on both so I'm not sure how they got out of sync. Any ideas?

What is the recommended fix?

Comment: `Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.` – https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: I ran 'composer require drush/drush' and now both are on version 10.2.2.

Comment: That sounds fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `composer require drush/drush` and now both are on version 10.2.x.